# Can we instantiate single object of core data in AppDelegate and Use it across complete application?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I want to instantiate one CoreData object in AppDelegate at app start and whenever I want to save data from any Controller, I will use that object, save it and use the same object to fetch data. Is there any bad impact of it in application?

Comment: What is the class or superclass of this object?

Comment: If you only have one, why are you using Core Data?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly fetch the same CoreData managed object from different parts of your app, edit it, and save it.  Just beware that you must not pass that managed object across threads. Also, you should save it from within a MOC (managed object context)'s queue, using performBlock: or performBlockAndWait:.

With that said, I strongly recommend you write yourself a class called something like CoreDataController (deriving from NSObject, is all).  Have all your CoreData methods live there, and do not expose your managed objects (your CoreData objects) beyond this class.  The data could be transferred to non-managed objects instead, and passed back to the rest of your app.  So all fetching, accessing, editing, deleting, and saving of any managed object would only be done within your CoreDataController, and always done within a MOC's queue by calling performBlock: or performBlockAndWait:.  This will keep you out of a lot of trouble!  :)

```
- (NSError*) createOrUpdateMyCoreDataGlobal:(NSString*)myData
{
    __block NSError* error = nil;
    [backgroundMOC performBlockAndWait:
     ^{
         NSError* fetchError;
         NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyCoreDataGlobalObject"];
         NSArray* globals = [backgroundMOC executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];
         MyCoreDataGlobalObject* global;
         if ([globals count] >= 1)
         {
             global = [globals firstObject];
             // you'll probably want to assert if you had more than one global, btw.
         }
         else if ([globals count] == 0)
         {
             global = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyCoreDataGlobalObject" inManagedObjectContext:backgroundMOC];
         }

         // now set whatever fields you need to set in your managed global object.  Maybe from parameters of this method?
         global.myData = myData;

         // now save your managed object
         [backgroundMOC save:&error];
    }];

   return error;
}
```

This is just an example method.  Consider that you probably wouldn't want to call this from main thread, as it'll block it until the method completes saving to CoreData.  So either change it to return void and switch to just performBlock: or call it from some another queue/thread.  And I don't really advise using the name "MyCoreDataGlobal" in production code. :)